# regex expressions fix

Tags: regex

i have this expression to allow numbers and uppercase and lowercase letters and i also need to allow characters like - (minus) and _ (underline) and no white spaces
can anyone help me with this please

```
if(txt1_len == 0 || txt1_len > 16 || txt1_len < 16 || !text1.value.match(
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-z\d]*$/))
```

the characters - and _ must not be mandatory but can be accepted. whitespace must not be accepted at all

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iF0qA7/7)?

```
if(!text1.value.match(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(\w|\-){16}$/)
```

Allowing only the characters you mentioned, needs exactly 16 of them and atleast one uppercase/lowercase/number...

[Personal note in case you are trying to ensure password strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: no that's not right. the code i have has mandatory for numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters. in your code you can enter if you want only numbers or letters

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)